# How can I design multiple buttons in a JSP each onclick, will display different input options

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

**My *Requirement Description*** :: I am designing a webapp in JAVA which interacts with the DB (MySQL) and registers an employee, updates the employee information, query an employee with employee id and removes a record. In the backend I am using Hibernate framework.

So I should have 4 buttons in my webpage :

- Add Employee
- Update Employee
- Remove Employee
- Query Employee

On clicking "Add Employee" it should request the user for some info like employee id, name etc. And other 3 buttons should be on hidden mode.
Same case on clicking other buttons also.

**My Problem** ::  I have designed my Webpage, how ever when I am clicking on any of the button, nothing is getting displayed. I am not sure where is the problem.
I have limited knowledge with JSP and CSS.
Please let me know where I am doing wrong and help me out in this situation

Here is my JSP code :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Employee Registration</title>

    <style type="text/css">
           .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
               overflow-y: scroll;
               background: #FBFBFB;
               max-height: 220px;
           }
    </style>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/js/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/button.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/design.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/jquery.gritter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/jsn.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/s1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/s2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Employee/WebContent/css/somu.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Employee/WebContent/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Employee/WebContent/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Employee/WebContent/js/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Employee/WebContent/js/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>               
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function display_ct() {
            var strcount
            var x = new Date()
            var x1 = x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById("time_div").innerHTML = x1;
            tt = display_c();
        }

        function display_c() {
            var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
            mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
        }

        function showDiv(element){
            var type = element.value;
            var effect = 'slide';
            var options = {direction: "left"};
            var duration = 500;
            if (type == 'Employee Registration') {
                                    alert("hi");
                $('#id_register').show();
                $('#id_update').hide();
                $('#id_removal').hide();
                $('#id_query').hide();
                alert("done");
            }
            else if (type == 'Employee Update'){
                 $('#id_register').hide();
                 $('#id_update').show();
                 $('#id_removal').hide();
                 $('#id_query').hide();   
            }
            else if (type == 'Employee Removal'){
                 $('#id_register').hide();
                 $('#id_update').hide();
                 $('#id_removal').show();
                 $('#id_query').hide();   
            }
            else if (type == 'Employee Query'){
                 $('#id_register').hide();
                 $('#id_update').hide();
                 $('#id_removal').hide();
                 $('#id_query').show();   
            }
        }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body onload=display_ct();>

        <div class="Bitmap">
             <img src="Images/online-employee-registration.jpg" style="height: 800px; width: 1355px; position: absolute; z-index: -1;" />
        </div>

            <table width="1300" class="myTable">
                <tr class="Labels">
                    <td align="center" width="800">
                        <b><font size="12"><label>Welcome to Employee Portal</label></font></b>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="1300" class="myTable">
            <tr class="Labels">
                <td align="right" width="200"><span id="time_div" class="clock2"></span></td>
            </tr>    
        </table>

        <center>
            <form action="EmployeeRegistration" name="UserDetailsContract" method="post"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="id_userDetailsContract">
            <table>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <input value="Employee Registration" 
                               type="button" 
                               onclick="showDiv(this);" />
                        <input value="Employee Update" 
                               type="button" 
                               onclick="showDiv(this);" />
                        <input value="Employee Removal" 
                               type="button" 
                               onclick="showDiv(this);" />
                        <input value="Employee Query" 
                               type="button" 
                               onclick="showDiv(this);" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>



            <div id="id_register" style="display: none">
                <table cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Name:<td><input type="text" name="name"/></tr>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Employee ID:<td><input type="text" name="employeeID"/></tr>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Email ID:<td><input type="text" name="emailID"/></tr>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Phone:<td><input type="text" name="phone" size="30" /></tr>
                        <tr><td width="20%">City:<td><input type="text" name="city" size="30" /></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" value="Register" />

            </div>
            <div id="id_query" style="display: none">
                <table cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Employee ID:<td><input type="text" name="employeeID"/></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />

            </div>
            <div id="id_update" style="display: none">
                <table cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Employee ID:<td><input type="text" name="employeeID"/></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" value="Update" />

            </div>
            <div id="id_removal" style="display: none">
                <table cellpadding="3pt" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td width="20%">Employee ID:<td><input type="text" name="employeeID"/></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" value="Remove" />

            </div>
           <!--  <p /> -->
            </form>
        </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have checked with keeping an alert("hi") inside :
if (type == 'Employee Registration') {
}
The alert statement is getting hit however the 2nd alert that is "done" that you can see in my above code is not getting hit.